# Combining records with overlapping linear ranges

Tags: python

Working with mileposted roadway (linear) data, I'm trying to combine attributes into a more compact list.  I know that sounds weird, but hopefully my example will explain:

Given:

| Id | From Milepost | To Milepost | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5} | 4.6 | 9.2 | Black |
| {07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5} | 4.6 | 9.2 | White |
| {07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5} | 4.6 | 9.2 | Red |
| {07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5} | 4.6 | 9.2 | Yellow |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 2.1 | 3.8 | Black |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 12.6 | 18.6 | Black |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 20.4 | 31.1 | Black |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 24.2 | 31.1 | Green |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 28.3 | 38.6 | Yellow |

Desired Result:

| Id | From Milepost | To Milepost | Combined Attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5} | 4.6 | 9.2 | Black, White, Red, Yellow |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 2.1 | 3.8 | Black |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 12.6 | 18.6 | Black |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 20.4 | 24.2 | Black |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 24.2 | 28.3 | Black, Green |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 28.3 | 31.1 | Black, Green, Yellow |
| {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF} | 31.1 | 38.6 | Yellow |

Essentially, I'm wanted to create new From- and To- Milepost ranges associated with "overlapping" records and attribute them as such.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - If you look at the mileposts in the output, you'll see how the overlap has been removed and the attributes have been combined - specifically, from milepost 20.4 to 38.6

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But what is your question about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a groupby:

**Sample input**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': {0: '{07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5}',  1: '{07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5}',  2: '{07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5}',  3: '{07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5}',  4: '{5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}',  5: '{5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}',  6: '{5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}',  7: '{5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}',  8: '{5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}'}, 'From Milepost': {0: 4.6,  1: 4.6,  2: 4.6,  3: 4.6,  4: 2.1,  5: 12.6,  6: 20.4,  7: 24.2,  8: 28.3}, 'To Milepost': {0: 9.2,  1: 9.2,  2: 9.2,  3: 9.2,  4: 3.8,  5: 18.6,  6: 31.1,  7: 31.1,  8: 38.6}, 'Attribute': {0: 'Black',  1: 'White',  2: 'Red',  3: 'Yellow',  4: 'Black',  5: 'Black',  6: 'Black',  7: 'Green',  8: 'Yellow'}})
```

**Code:**

```
df.groupby(['Id', 'From Milepost', 'To Milepost'])['Attribute'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

**Output:**

```
                                       Id  ...                    Attribute
0  {07035D31-C011-4913-B500-06D12314C3B5}  ...  [Black, White, Red, Yellow]
1  {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}  ...                      [Black]
2  {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}  ...                      [Black]
3  {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}  ...                      [Black]
4  {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}  ...                      [Green]
5  {5454498F-FF7B-4900-835D-794349C434BF}  ...                     [Yellow]
[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Andreas - I was also looking to remove the overlaps and combine the attributes from milepost 20.4 to 38.6. We had this solved using SQL cursors and multiple loops years back, but the code has since been lost to the ravages of time.